# Should I use polymorphic relationships when using different columns by entity?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, database-design, polymorphism, relational-database

I have a few tables that I'm unsure if it makes sense to use polymorphic relationships, because in one of them there are different columns/attributes.

(Note: I'm building in laravel 5.5)

Here is a simplified version of the tables:

```
pick_up_points, shipping_entities, products
  id
  name

pick_up_points_periods
  id
  pick_up_point_id
  week_day // -> a number matching the day of the week (0->Monday, ..., 6->Sunday)
  start_time // ex: "24:59"
  end_time

shipping_entities_delivery_periods  // (the shipping entities follow the same delivery pattern between them)
  id
  shipping_entity_id
  week_day
  start_time
  end_time

product_promotion_periods
  id
  product_id
  start_date // ex: "2017-10-25"
  end_date
```

---

### I was thinking in 2 possible ways to use polymorphic relationships.

**Case 1** - create the table periods just to replace the tables pick_up_points_periods and shipping_entities_delivery_periods

```
periods
  id
  periodable_type
  week_day
  start_time
  end_time
```

In this case (1) it makes more sense to me, since they use the same fields/columns, but it would leave another periods table out.

---

**Case 2** - create the table periods to replace all *_periods tables (tables pick_up_points_periods, shipping_entities_delivery_periods and product_promotion_periods)

```
periods
  id
  periodable_id
  periodable_type
  week_day
  start_time
  end_time
  start_date
  end_date
```

in this case (2) it makes less sense to me, since they use different fields/columns, but it would fit all periods context tables together (by reducing even more the number of tables).
  . and there would be records with unused columns if they were for example pick_up_points_periods or product_promotion_periods.

---

### My line of thought:

In the laravel v5.5 documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations), there are 2 examples of polymorphic relationships for:

- comments - that exist for both posts and videos
- tags - that exist for posts and videos

For me, both comments and tags are entities that make sense to be polymorphic, because they have always the same shared fields across the other entities (posts, videos or any other i can think off)

However, for periods I can think of many kinds of them, like for example:

- time period of a day of the week
- time period (of every day)
- date period ([start_date:'2017-02-28', end_date:'2017-05-31'])
- timestamp period (ex: [start_date:'2017-02-28 08:00:00', end_date:'2017-05-31 20:00:00'])
- weeks of the month (example: only at the 1st 2 weeks of each month)
- n week day of the month (example: only at the 3rd Tuesday of each month)
- a mix of them ([start/end]_[time/date/timestamp], week_day, month_[day/week]), ...

where each entity / table could have different attributes / columns even if they would still fit the "periods" context.

- I could build a polymorphic table with all the fields (like case 2), but they could be empty/null depending on the periodable_type

  - but at least could also predict a change of the period pattern (/ fields used)

    - or just adding the new fields when needed even if not all types used

---

I tried to search for something like if there is some "*best practices on when to use or not polymorphic relationships*", but i could not properly find a similar situation.

So I would like to know if: should use case 1, case 2 or just not use polymorphic relations at all? what are the pros/cons of each one? Is there any best practices for this matter?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you're right to keep two tables, because the periods are different. What do the time periods in the first two tables represent--location schedules, location hours of operation, or...? I think you can make a reusable object for them that describes what those periods are. The second table sounds like it could contain date range periods.

Comment: in each record of the pick_up_points_periods, you can tell for example, that in that pick up point location (pick_up_point_id) you can pick up your order on a Monday from 09:00 (start_time) to 18:00 (end_time), and then you add another record for another day of the week for the same pick up point (or another). For the shipping_entities_delivery_periods it's the same, but for when a certain entity (like one of the persons that make deliveries) will be available in a certain day of the week and it's time in that week day (with different records for different days of the week).

Comment: and for the product_promotion_periods table, in each record, you can indicate that a product (product_id) will have a promotion from 2017-10-31 (day 31 of October of 2017)(start_date) to 2017-12-31 (end of the year) (end_date). Where in the period table in case 1 periodable_id matches the pick_up_point_id and shipping_entity_id, and in the case 2 it matches the same ones plus the product_id (of the product_promotion_periods).

Comment: just for better clarification, the pick_up_points_periods and the shipping_entities_delivery_periods would be equivalent to a table to store the weekly schedule of students (where is equal in all weeks).

Comment: I think you could call the first table _schedules_ and have `schedulable_id` and `schedulable_type` ... as for the second one I would have the following tables _products_ which has many _promotions_ which has many _promotions_periods_ (or _period_promotion_ if you prefer the convention) ... I think there is an advantage to being able to reuse promotions (like seasonal promotions)

Comment: I guess the periods table from case 1 could be called schedules since it fits the type of data. About the product promotion, i understood the idea about reusing promotions periods, but it just happens that for system I’m implementing there isn't a promotion season for a group of products, where it varies more specifically for an individual product (not sure if it will change in the future, but at least for now it's like that).